# browser.saveScreenshot(), not creating file (nodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, automation, appium

I'm writing automation tests for a [Cordova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cordova) app using Appium and web_selenium.

Here is my code for taking a screenshot:

```
it("should take screenshot", function() {
    return browser.contexts()
        .then(function(cnt){
            console.log(cnt[1]);
                return browser.context(cnt[1]);
        })
        .then(function(){
            return browser
            browser.saveScreenshot("/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/VGimages/nexLogin.png")
                .sleep(500)
        });
});
```

It passes the test, but no image is created.

Comment: posted answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086403/browser-savescreenshot-hangs-when-called/41089011#41089011

Answer (score 1):

In your `then` statement, you're calling `return browser` before `browser.saveScreenshot()`. `return` stops the execution of a statement and returns a value. Essentially, it's telling your function to ignore any code that is written after it.

Depending on how you're using `browser`, you either need to move the `return browser` to a point after `browser.saveScreenshot()`, or simply combine the two as `return browser.saveScreenshot()`.

Comment: When I do that it hangs when it reaches the screenShot command.

Comment: made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086403/browser-savescreenshot-hangs-when-called