# browser.saveScreenshot() hangs when called

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, automation, appium

Hi I am writing automation tests for a Cordova application.
I want to save screenshots of each page, here is my code.

```
 it("should take screenshot", function() {
     return browser.contexts().then(function(cnt){
         console.log(cnt[1]);
         return browser.context(cnt[1]);
           }).then(function(){
             return browser.saveScreenshot("/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy/VGimages/nexLogin.png")
});
});
```

Here is my Appium console:

```
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/610d95af-6501-4c72-ac38-0184a8608dfd/screenshot {}
[MJSONWP] Driver proxy active, passing request on via HTTP proxy
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /wd/hub/session/610d95af-6501-4c72-ac38-0184a8608dfd/screenshot] to [GET http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/4d5f3f8a24e28f7fbf65eebc47cc02d8/screenshot] with body: {}

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status {}

[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []

[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.5.3"...
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 14 ms - 83
```

Im new to automation and JS, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out savescreenshot(), is not compatible with cordova applications.
However I did find a solution!

Using these commands we can take a screen shot directly from the emulator:

```
adb pull /sdcard/screenshot.png screenshot.png
adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/screenshot.png
```

So how can we do this programmatically?
well nodeJS has 'child_process' which can call commands to the terminal!

```
      it("should take screenshot", function() {
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    exec('adb shell /system/bin/screencap -p /sdcard/tester.png', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
       if (error) {
         console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
         return;
       }
       console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
       console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    });
    exec('adb pull /sdcard/tester.png tester.png', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
           if (error) {
             console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
             return;
           }
           console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
           console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        });


});
```

So using something like this ^, I can take a screenshot that is saved to the emulators sd card, and then pull this screenshot onto my directory!